# Resolving 'Legend' conflict IE 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

The following CSS works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.  But for some reason IE 9 it isn't displaying the `legend`. The other CSS is displaying properly in IE 9. I have experimented but cannot find the answer. It should display orange `legend` headers with white text and a black border.

Site address:  http://www.mconchicago.com

**CSS :**

```
legend{
    color: #fff;
    background: #ffa20c;
    border: 1px solid #781351;
    width: 49.2em;
    padding: 2px 6px
}
```

My stylesheet is a mess as I learn by trying things. I think there might be a conflict in it somewhere.

Full Stylesheet can be viewed [here](http://mconchicago.com/main.css%20here):

Comment: Sometime after this string of events took place the entire site was relaunched.  I have archived the old files.  If you want to see the results of this Flash advice, for the time-being at least, you can view http://www.mconchicago.com/MCON/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hazard a guess at it not working because you're trying to put the heading in a legend element. Legends are only for forms, but this is a page / section heading rather than a form legend.

Replace <legend> with <h1> and update your CSS accordingly.

You should also get used to writing valid HTML as invalid code can also lead to inconsistencies between browsers as they attempt to make sense of your code in their own ways. Use the W3C validator and work through the errors

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mconchicago.com%2F

Comment: Thanks very much for the tip on h1.  That was enough to get things squared away on a preliminary basis.  Thanks also for the validator link.  I realize the code needs to be cleaned up and this will help.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is not only on the orange header, you have **61 Errors and 15 warnings** on your document markup.

See [this link](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.mconchicago.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) to know exactly what errors are, where are they located, and how to solve them!

---

**Also, you should read a bit about HTML:**

[Google's HTML, CSS, and Javascript from the Ground Up](http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/)

[Opera Web Standards Curriculum](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/#toc)

[SitePoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/)

[The MDN (Mozilla's Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs)

[W3.org HTML element reference](http://www.w3.org/html/wiki/Elements)

**Source:** http://w3fools.com/ (thanks to [Spudley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352765/spudley) )

Comment: Thank you for the references.  That first link looks like a real time-saver

Comment: That link was generated by [this site!](http://validator.w3.org/) To use it, just place the full URL to the page you need validation!

Comment: +1 for the link to the W3C validator, but -1 for linking to w3Schools. You'll learn lots there, but not all of it will be correct.

Comment: @Spudley, any website of your preference or recommendation? I can update my answer with a more reliable link!

Comment: @Zuul - I refer you to http://w3fools.com/, which is basically a massive rant against w3Schools. However, it does contain a list of better alternative resources (scroll about a page or two down).

Comment: @Spudley, didn't know that site, is bookmarked now ;)  _ps: answer updated!_

Answer (score 1):

Sometime after this string of events took place the entire site was relaunched.  I have archived the old files.  If you want to see the results of this  advice, for the time-being at least, you can view http://www.mconchicago.com/MCON/